# Space shuttle cabin atmosphere system

Tags: space-shuttle

I see from looking at the space shuttle cabin air supply system that it provides O2 and N2 through a common manifold into a 14.7 psi regulator. What is not clear to me is where the cabin air goes, and if there's much of a flow through that regulator, or if its mostly idle. The spec suggests it can manage 20lb/hr. My question is when and how much it operated...
Did they continuously or periodically vent cabin air only to have it top up from this system? Is the system only supplying fresh air when the cabin pressure falls, as a result of leaks or waste dumping? Any info which helps me understand the way in which air was supplied through this regulator, especially when and why, would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the normal orbit configuration for the Orbiter's Pressure Control System (PCS).

[image]

~850 psi O2 (yellow) flows in from the cryogenic tanks (also used to feed the fuel cells) in the Orbiter midbody, over a heat exchanger with the Freon loop which warms the O2, through a flow restrictor and filter into a 100 psi regulator.

~3000 psi N2 (purple) flows in from dedicated tanks in the midbody through a 200 psi regulator, then a filter, into the cabin plumbing.

One of the two PCS systems is configured to flow either O2 or N2 through the cabin regulator.  The diagram shows PCS System 1 configured to flow. Nothing flows unless the cabin pressure drops below 14.7.  When the pressure does drop below 14.7, the regulator cracks and start flowing gas. Which gas it flows is controlled by the O2/N2 Control Valve, which in turn is controlled by a circuit that senses the partial pressure of O2 (PPO2) in the cabin.

If the PPO2 is less than 2.95 psi, the system will flow O2. If it is greater than 3.45, it will flow N2.  For intermediate values of PPO2, the valve remains in its last position.  Again, nothing flows unless the cabin pressure drops below 14.7

[image]

Nothing major was intentionally vented but O2 is consumed by crew breathing, N2 is consumed by (minor but always present) leakage overboard (there is a nominal 3 lb/hr vent through the vacuum vent system all the time), toilet ops, etc.

[image]

([diagram source](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/USA006020%20Rev%20B%20-%20Environmental%20Control%20and%20Life%20Support%20System%2020061023.pdf))

The diagram says "1st half" because midway through the mission, the systems were configured to flow from System 2, just to even out wear and tear.

As far as flow amounts, you can see the flow restrictors on the oxygen lines which limit the O2 flow to ~25 lb/hr, but the cabin reg can flow up to 75 lb/hr or more if it kicks into high flow - note there are no flow restrictors on the nitrogen lines.

Control switches for the electrically operated valves are found on Panel L2, to the left of the commander's seat. Here's a picture I took of the panel in Endeavour. You can see how the schematic drawn on the panel matches the drawing above pretty well.  Valves that don't have switches on this panel are manually operated valves located in the middeck.

[image]

Reference: used to teach the system for a living. The picture comes from training material.  Put everything in past tense.  The writeup in the [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/USA007587%20Rev%20A%20-%20Shuttle%20Crew%20Operations%20Manual%2020081215.pdf) is pretty good, page 2.9-4

Comment: I was waiting for you to reply :) I'm currently looking at a doc called ECLSS 21002. Hope you don't mind a few follow up questions. The cabin positive pressure relief valve is described as opening at 15.5, reaching full flow at 16, and reseating below 15.5. Can you tell me, is this an audible operation? What's it sound like if so? What sounds do the other valves make?

Comment: ECLSS 21002 is a great reference, I didn't know it was available (JSC didn't post it on their FDF page). You can read about the vacuum vent and the constant leakage in chapter 5.4  The cabin pressure relief valve never operated as far as I know, it would have been considered a huge screw-up if the cabin pressure had gotten that high.  The only comment I ever heard about PCS sounds was after STS-86, they did a huge repress of Mir, and the CDR told me that they had audible flow noise, and even got frost on the nozzles (the cabin reg outlets were on MO10W, the ceiling of the toilet compartment)

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what is the date on your copy of ECLSS 21002?  And sure, ask followups!

Comment: Got it somewhere on nasa.gov. Its 2006 version.

Comment: Thanks! That's probably the "final version".

Comment: Am I right in thinking the whole system was unable to automatically maintain a suitable PPO2 at a lower cabin pressure, for example if the orbiter should dock with something pressurized to 12psi..    Might just be a hypothetical situation. Wondering if it was ever discussed and if a procedure existed? The cabin regulator wasn't adjustable, was it?

Comment: You are right about the automatic part.  The cabin was often depressurized to 10.2 psi in preparation for EVAs. In that situation, the pressure and PPO2 had to be managed manually. The 10.2 operations are described in that same ECLSS 21002 manual. The procedures themselves are in the EVA checklist, section 1. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/492872main_EVA_G_H_20.pdf

Comment: There were 8 psi regulators as well, but they only came into play in a cabin leak scenario.

Comment: Haven't gotten to the eva bit yet, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: The 100psi section of the O2 supply has a pressure relief valve which cracks at 245psi and vents into the cabin. Why the cabin? I guess the cabin relief will take care of it, but why not into the vacuum line directly?

Comment: Found this in the crew ops manual only: "Makeup O2 for metabolic usage is 
provided by a bleed orifice inserted on orbit into LEH O2 8 quick disconnect on panel MO69M".  how come this isn't even shown on the diagrams above? According to this, only gas to replace leaks flows through the o2/n2 manifold.. so why have both? Surely if this bleed oriface didn't exist the o2/n2 manifold would supply air replacing both metabolic o2 loss and air leaks? I don't get the point of the bleed, nor why such an important function isn't shown in the diagrams... any chance for clarification on that?

Comment: @Innovine where is this relief valve you are talking about? Document, page reference please?  I'm not remembering this but it's been a while.

Comment: The 245psig relief is mentioned in crew ops 2.9-6 (same page as the mention of the bleed oriface). interestingly, the n2 200psi section has a similar valve, which vents into the vacuum line.

Comment: The LEH O2 QD is shown on the drawing in my answer. It's just to the left of the N2 crossover valve.  The bleed orifice was just to reduce wear and tear on the O2/N2 control valve - if the bleed could replace metabolic use, then the O2/N2 control valve could stay in N2.

Comment: I remember nothing about that O2 regulator relief valve. It appears to be provided to protect against the O2 regulator failing open, but I don't know details about it.

Comment: I see the LEH valve, and assumed it was a closed loop to the suits only (haven't looked into that yet). I am a bit surprised this main source of breathable O2 isn't more clearly indicated, but hey, I sure am learning stuff now :)

Comment: There's more about the bleed orifice in the 21002 manual page 2-27.